# Too much space at end of chapter

Tags: spacing, page-breaking, lyx

When writing my thesis in LyX, I encountered the following problem:
After finishing a chapter, I wrote `\break` in order for LyX to start writing the next section in the next page.
The problem is that LyX automatically spaced the last page of the first section, so that the last word will appear in the end of the page. It caused a very big space between the beginning of this page and its ending.

Does someone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 4):

The `\break` command is not documented in the LaTeX manual, and for a reason: it acts differently in LR mode and between paragraphs. It's still in the LaTeX kernel because some old documents may have used it.

In order to break a page there are other choices:

1. `\pagebreak`, which will honor the `\flushbottom` or `\raggedbottom` setting; the first one is the default in the `book` class
2. `\newpage`, which will end a page at the spot, filling the remaining part with white space.
3. `\clearpage`, which is an enhanced version of `\newpage`, in that it will also flush the floating object queues, inserting the floats, possibly as page floats, before starting the new page.

Thus what you need here is, probably,

```
\newpage
```

Comment: and `\cleardoublepage`

Comment: @Stephen In this case I don't think that `\cleardoublepage` is what's wanted. But it's a possibility.